# why "based' is transitive verb in following sentence?

Tags: verbs

> a story based upon real-life events

source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/base

Why "based" is a transitive verb in the above sentence?

Comment: "Based" is an adjective here, not a verb. The adjective phrase "based upon real-life events" modifies "story".

Comment: @BillJ Please make that an answer. The only answer so far is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

It’s right there in the dictionary definition of “base” that you linked to (my emphasis):

> To find a foundation or basis for : to find a base (see BASE entry 1
> sense 3a) for —**usually used with on or upon**

It’s a transitive verb because that’s how the word is generally used.

Comment: I think it's better to classify "based" as an adjective here, not a verb. The adjective phrase "based upon real-life events" then modifies "story".